# Why is this code not printing the directory contents?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a Python newbie and need to create a script that will do parse some files and put them into a SQL db. So I am trying to create smaller scripts that do what I want, then combine them into a larger script.

To that end, I am trying run this code:

```
import os

fileList = []

testDir = "/home/me/somedir/dir1/test"

for i in os.listdir(testDir):
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        fileList.append(i)

for fileName in fileList:
    print(fileName)
```

When I look at the output, I do not see any files listed. I tried the path without quotes and got stack errors. So searching showed I need the double quotes.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code that works fine:

```
import os

in_path = "/home/me/dir/"

for dir_path, subdir_list, file_list in os.walk(in_path):
    for fname in file_list:
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, fname)
        print(full_path)
```

I can use full_path to do my next step.

If anyone has any performance tips, feel free to share them. Or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you're most likely ejecuting your script from a folder outside your `testdir`, [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) need the full path name of the file so it can check is that is a lile or not ([`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) return the names), if the full path is not provide then it will check is there is a file with the given name in the same folder from which the script is executed, to fix this you need to give the full path name of that file, you can do it with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) like this

```
for name in os.listdir(testDir):
    if os.path.isfile( os.path.join(testDir,name) ):
        fileList.append(name)
```

or if you also want the full path

```
for name in os.listdir(testDir):
    path = os.path.join(testDir,name)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        fileList.append(path)
```